# How to select values in dropdownlist with selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc, testng

I am using selenium, TestNG and java with eclipse to perform an automated test. I'm having success with commands like click on a button (selenium.click ("button"), pass values ​​to textboxes (selenium.type ("component", "value") and clicks too, but when it comes with a component type dropdown list (relating to common or asp.net MVC) I can not select the field with the command selenium.select ("field", "value").

To select the values ​​and even the fields, I am using XPath to it, but even so, with the dropdown list can not, or can partially.

When a drop-down list accepts the value I type, I can use the selenium.click but if not, nothing I've tried so far works.

Answer (score 2):

using webdriver you can do it with Select class i have posted a code which was working below please 
   have a look on that,Select Class had api to select the drop down values by its index as well as          value,have a look on Select api for more info

```
   public static void dropdown() 
    {
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://demosthenes.info/blog/166/HTML-Forms-Drop-down-Menus");
    Select sele = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("state")));
    sele.selectByIndex(1);
    }
```

Comment: Sorry this is not gonna work. Select class only works for elements with <select> tags which is not the case for asp.net. I am trying to find the solution for this problem as well, but no luck so far...

Comment: @Lucas if possible please post your html dom so that we can also help you to solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to select elements from dropdown list. Below are some of them you can keep them as common drop-down operation and call what ever method you need.

```
//select the dropdown using "select by visible text"
        public static void dropDownSelectByText(WebElement webElement, String VisibleText){
            Select selObj=new Select(webElement);
            selObj.selectByVisibleText(VisibleText);
        }

//select the dropdown using "select by index"
public static void dropDownSelectByIndex(WebElement webElement, int IndexValue){
    Select selObj=new Select(webElement);
    selObj.selectByIndex(IndexValue);
}

//select the dropdown using "select by value"
public static void dropDownSelectByValue(WebElement webElement, String Value){
    Select selObj=new Select(webElement);
    selObj.selectByValue(Value);
}
```

You can call above methods like

```
CommonPageOperations.dropDownSelectByValue(selectSubClientFromDropDownXpath,strSubClientName);
```

Drop down list appear only if mouse move to specific location, Then you have to use Actions as well

```
public void mouseMoveToExpandIcon(){
        Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        action.moveToElement(expandButtonXpath).perform();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
WebElement select = driver.findElement(By.id("selection"));
List<WebElement> options = select.findElements(By.tagName("option"));
for (WebElement option : options) {
  if("Germany".equals(option.getText()))
    option.click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
WebElement dBox1= (new    WebDriverWait(driver,10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("selection""))).    selectByVisibleText("");
actions.moveToElement(dBox1);
actions.click();
actions.perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Select in selenium to select from the drop down value.

//by ID

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
new Select (driver.findElement(By.id("usState"))).selectByVisibleText("FL");
```

//by XPath

```
new Select (driver.findElement(By.xpath("xPath for dropdown"))).selectByVisibleText("FL");
```